# How to get latest record for matching ID and date in Power BI Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables:

`Table A`, which indicates where my truck is for each day,

```
Date        Truck   Region
5/20/2018   1014    NY
5/21/2018   1014    NJ
```

and `Table B` (which contains when my truck inspection was done for each day). Sometimes there may be more than one inspection record, but I only need the last one by truck by day. As you can see, I added a rank column. Truck 1014 has two records for 5/20/2018, but the last one gets ranked as 1 (I will filter the table by 1).

```
Date        Time              Truck  Rank
5/20/2018   5/20/18 9:00 AM   1014    2
5/20/2018   5/20/18 2:00 PM   1014    1
5/21/2018   5/21/18 2:50 PM   1014    1
```

I want to merge those two tables together. The reason I ask how to do it in the query editor is that, in the relationship view, you cannot create a relationship on two columns. For example, in my example, I want to join data by date and by truck number, which I cannot. What is the right direction for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query editor, you can use the Merge Queries button under the Home tab.

(You'll need to hold down the Ctrl key to select multiple columns.)

[image: Merge]

Once you've merged, just expand the columns from `Table B` that you want to bring over (e.g. `Time` and `Rank`). If you did not filter `Rank = 1` before merging, you can include it when expanding and filter afterward.

---

Note that you can also use the `LOOKUPVALUE` DAX function outside of the query editor. As a new column on `Table A`:

```
Time = LOOKUPVALUE('Table B'[Time],
           'Table B'[Date], [Date],
           'Table B'[Truck], [Truck],
           'Table B'[Rank], 1)
```